# Message: Required parameter 'hyperVGeneration' is missing (null) while creating a Managed Disk image from blob storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-disk

- **Package Name**: azure.mgmt.compute
- **Package Version**: v2020_06_01
- **Operating System**: ubuntu 18.04
- **Python Version**:  Python 3.7

**Describe the bug**
Instead of creating the disk it throws `Message: Required parameter 'hyperVGeneration' is missing (null).`  error.

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Run below code

```
compute_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ComputeManagementClient)
async_creation = compute_client.images.create_or_update(
    '7AQVDL2J',
    'test',
    {
        'location': 'westeurope',
        'storage_profile': {
           'os_disk': {
              'os_type': 'Linux',
              'os_state': "Generalized",
              'blob_uri': 'https://bg09.blob.core.windows.net/vm-images/non-existent.vhd',
              'caching': "ReadWrite",
           }
        }
    }
)
```

**Expected behavior**
Disk should be created

**Error**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/azure/mgmt/compute/v2020_06_01/operations/_images_operations.py", line 125, in create_or_update
    **operation_config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/azure/mgmt/compute/v2020_06_01/operations/_images_operations.py", line 81, in _create_or_update_initial
    raise exp
msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Azure Error: InvalidParameter
Message: Required parameter 'hyperVGeneration' is missing (null).
Target: hyperVGeneration
```

Link to git issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/12762

If anyone found a workaround for this, please share....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, to fix it, we need to add a [`hyper_vgeneration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.models.image?view=azure-python#parameters) when you creating the image.

You could refer to the sample below, it works fine on my side.

```
from azure.mgmt.compute.models import DiskCreateOption
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile

compute_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ComputeManagementClient)
async_creation = compute_client.images.create_or_update(
    'groupname',
    'test123',
    {
        'location': 'eastus',
        'storage_profile': {
           'os_disk': {
              'os_type': 'Linux',
              'os_state': "Generalized",
              'blob_uri': 'https://joystoragev2.blob.core.windows.net/vhds2/destDisk.vhd',
              'caching': "ReadWrite",
           }
        },
        'hyper_vgeneration': 'V1'
    }
)
image_resource = async_creation.result()
print(image_resource)
```

[image]

Comment: Cool.. let me try it.

Comment: It worked.. Thanks!! I was pretty busy with other tasks. Sorry.